# Using arrayList to create two 'decks' of 'cards'

Tags: java, arraylist

I am wanting to use `ArrayList` to create two virtual card decks for which I will create attributes in the form of objects and then apply these to each virtual card in both decks.

I was thinking something along the lines of this:

```
 public Deck1(){
     ArrayList<Integer> baseballDeck1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(25);
  }
```

But I think creating the two decks individually would be inefficient and so here I am looking for some assistance. Many thanks in advance for anyone who replies.

Comment: Why do you think creating two separate decks is inefficient? What exactly are you planning to do with them?

Comment: If you can provide more information about what you're eventually looking to do with your two decks, then it might be clearer to see if it really might be inefficient or not!

Comment: Hi unholySheep, I plan on creating a simple card game with the two decks in which each card has a number of attributes which are compared.

Comment: Don't optimize too early. Make sure your program works and is readable and logical first. Then, if needed, optimize the code while making sure that it works the same.

Comment: Thanks Andreas I'll definitely take that in.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality first: you have two decks of cards if they are treated separately. If you put them together and shuffle, you create a new deck of cards (consisting out of the two earlier ones).

Just some sample code that can make use of your `Deck` implementations. Maybe `FullDeck` extends `Deck`.

```
deck1 = new FullDeck();
deck2 = new FullDeck();
deck = new Deck();
deck.add(deck1);
deck.add(deck2);
deck.shuffle();
System.out.println("Top Card: "+deck.peekTop().toString);
```

There are so many implementations you can make - I have seen nice samples with `Enum` types. Maybe in your case you need to stay generic enough, having cards that can be created at will with the needed attributes.

The point as others are already trying to make - why are you even bothering about optimizing. Focus on your model first, create your proof of concept.